# Standalone MongoDB installation for Production

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, production, replicaset

I want to deploy MongoDB to Kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes, there is no chance to add another node in the future.

I want to deploy MongoDB as standalone because both node will be able to access to same disk space via NFS and I don't have requirements for replication or high availability. However, in the MongoDB docs, it is clearly stated that standalone deployment is not suitable for production environment.

[MongoDB Deploy Standalone](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/deploy-standalone/)

> You can deploy a standalone MongoDB instance for Cloud Manager to manage. Use standalone instances for testing and development. Do not use these deployments for production systems as they lack replication and high availability.

What kind of drawbacks I can face? Should I deploy as replica set with arbiter instance? If yes, why?

Comment: Just keep in mind that kubernetes(stateless microservices orchestrator) is not very suitable for stateful applications(databases) especially in production. Afcourse you can deploy it via statefullset if there is no other options , but there will be alot of customizations that you need to take care making the orchestration abit over complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can deploy a Standalone MongoDB for production. But if this node fails, then your application is not available anymore. If you don't have any requirement for availability then go for a Standalone MongoDB.

However, running 2 MongoDB services which access the same physical disk (i.e. `dbPath`) will not work. Each MongoDB instance need to have a dedicated data folder.

In your case, I would suggest a [Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/). All data from one node will be replicated to the other one. If one node fails then the application goes into "read/only" mode.

You can deploy an arbiter instance on the primary node. If the secondary node goes down, then the application is still fully available.

Comment: There is a possibility that any node can fail at anytime, there is no so-called primary or high-available node. So there is no guarantee where I should deploy the arbiter. Deploying 2 arbiter might be a solution but it is also not preferred. It seems having [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) with scale 1 is the most suitable solution. Then, I will have 1 instance at a time which accesses `dbPath `, and can orchestrate to other node when working node fails.

Comment: In a Replica Set the **majority** of nodes must be up. With two members you don't have any majority if one goes down. You would have to deploy the arbiter on a third host.

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to deploy as replicaSet for production , however if you deploy as standalone and you have 2x kubernetes nodes  , kubernetes can ensure there is always 1x running instance attached to the NFS storage in any of the available nodes , but the risk is that when the data on the storage is corrupted you will not have where to replicate from unless you do often backups and you dont care if you miss some recenly inserted data ...